# tsql update query, that update fields on run

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table (Table1):

```
+----+-----+
|Type|Value|
+----+-----+
|P   |4    |
+----+-----+
|P   |20   |
+----+-----+
|S   |0    |
+----+-----+
|S   |0    |
+----+-----+
|S   |0    |
+----+-----+
```

i'm running the following query :

```
update Table1 set value = ( select sum(value) FROM Table1 ) where Type = 'S'
```

the result would be 24 for all fields with value = 'S'

what i need is to take in consideration the values that have been updated on run.
result that i need :

```
+----+-----+
|Type|Value|
+----+-----+
|P   |4    |
+----+-----+
|P   |20   |
+----+-----+
|S   |24   |
+----+-----+
|S   |48   |
+----+-----+
|S   |96   |
+----+-----+
```

how this can be done in a simple query ?

thank you,

Comment: Try searching for "SQL Server running totals" solutions. Admittedly, your particular problem has a little twist to it, but still, running totals appears to be the central theme.

Answer (score 1):

`DECLARE @ID int 

DECLARE cur CURSOR local select ID from table1 where Type = 'S' 

FETCH cur into @ID 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 

BEGIN 

    update Table1 set value = ( select sum(value) FROM Table1 ) where ID=@ID 

    FETCH cur into @ID 

END 

Close cur 

DEALLOCATE  cur`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used the cursor method. But this invokes a critical performance when using the cursor on a huge table. is there any other possible solution ?